# Perspective transformation, How to locate the 4 points in the original image so that the viewing angle would be right above the scene

Tags: opencv, camera, perspective

What I am trying to do is to make the people's sizes in the output image all the same. So I performed a perspective transformation so that the viewing angle is right above the scene. The scene picture is showing below:[image]

The functions I am using is cv2.getPerspectiveTransform and cv2.warpPerspective, and this method need 4 points on the input image and corresponding points on the output image. For the 4 points on the output image, i always choose the four corners. However it's very hard to choose the 4 points on the input image.My mentor told me the 4 points must choose from the vanishing lines(parallel to each other), Below is an example of how i chose the 4 points on the input image in this way:

[image]

However, the people's sizes are still different, the people on the upper side of the image are larger and they are blur. Then I tried to change the 4 points by looking at the output image(not following the vanishing lines,just change the points based on the output), here is what i got:

[image]

It's better but it's too complicated, it took me quite a long time to adjust the four points. Are there any easier ways to locate the 4 points on the input image so that the people's sizes on the output image is the same? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: after removing lens distortion you can choose 4 points on a plane (table or floor) and corresponding points in real space coordinates.

Comment: because of perspective effects you'll never get perfectly same sized people, you'll get strange distortions for everything that's not on your reference plane and you'll always have blurred parts

Comment: @Micka So my first way is better than my second way?

Comment: you must choose points whose relative locations are known in real world. so for example use 4 corners of a single table (if table size/ratio is known or can be approximated)

Comment: but removal of lens distortion is important!!!

Comment: if tables are fixed to ground and are placed on a regular grid you can use multiple tables to reduce error

Comment: @Micka How should i remove the lens distortion?

Comment: it is typically done with calibration patterns. google for "lens distortion correction" or "undistort camera"