# How to make people with different distances to the camera appear to be the same sizes?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

Now I am doing a project which is called crowd estimation. I am focused on estimating the crowd levels in canteens. My approach is based on subtracting the background and only keeping the people in the foreground. The people are represented by white pixels and the background is black. So I can estimate the crowd level by counting the white pixels in the foreground. However, this needs people with different distances to the camera  appear to be the same sizes. Otherwise, the white pixels for the people sitting near to the camera may be 5 times another person who sits far away from the camera. This is not I want, I want their pixels to be almost the same. Below is a screenshot of the canteen:

[image]

The first way I have tried is by segmenting the scene into different regions, the near regions are assigned with less weights, the far regions are assigned with more weights. However, the segmentation and weights assigning are all done manually, and it's hard to judge the line to segment and the weights assigned to each region. I use a picture below to show how it is done:

[image]

Another way I have tried is the perceptive transform, choosing four points on the input image and mapping them to the 4 points on the output image. However it's hard to choose the 4 points and it's hard to decide whether the people's sizes are the same after the transformation. It's shown below:

[image]

Can anyone provide a good way to solve this people's sizes problem(due too different distances)? Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ask this question on the opencv forums you'll get a better response there. as an aside, have you tried some other basic operations on the foreground pixels? you can mask them out like you are currently but perhaps looking for 'blobs' of heads is a better way to approach this than straight pixel counting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perspective transformation, How to locate the 4 points in the original image so that the viewing angle would be right above the scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413383/perspective-transformation-how-to-locate-the-4-points-in-the-original-image-so)